# Trap mouse click in Safari with Applescript

Tags: safari, onclick, applescript

I am trying to trap mouse click events in Safari with Applescript.  My Applescript does what it needs to do, but I want to terminate if the user clicks on the document in Safari.  I would like to set up an On_Click event in Applescript that would fire if the user clicks in the Safari document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how to "trap" a mouse event with applescript. You'd have to use objective-c and the cocoa APIs for that.

However you might do it another way. Here's a quick example. Save this as a stay-open applescript application. When you run it the Safari window will scroll. To pause the scrolling just click the dock icon of the applescript. If you click the dock icon again then the scrolling will start again and vice versa. You'll notice that every time you click the dock icon the "on reopen" handler is executed which toggles the shouldScroll variable between true and false.

Anyway, I hope this gives you an idea for making your own script work. Remember you can quit the stay-open applescript by right-clicking on its dock icon and choosing quit. Good luck.

```
property shouldScroll : missing value
property theCounter : missing value
property counterMaxValue : missing value

on run
    tell application "Safari" to activate
    set shouldScroll to true
    set theCounter to 0
    set counterMaxValue to 2000
end run

on reopen
    tell application "Safari" to activate
    set shouldScroll to not shouldScroll
end reopen

on idle
    if shouldScroll then
        if theCounter is greater than counterMaxValue then set theCounter to 0
        tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
            do JavaScript "window.scroll (0," & (theCounter as text) & ")"
        end tell
        set theCounter to theCounter + 20
    end if
    return 0.1
end idle
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried running the script but it did not scroll my Safari window.  Maybe because I don't know what you mean by "Save this as a stay-open applescript".  Also what is the "dock icon"?  Thanks!

Comment: Somebody also suggested that I look at UI Actions from PFiddlesoft.  I have downloaded it, but have not tried it yet.

Comment: Copy/paste the code into AppleScript Editor. Save. At the bottom of the save window make the file format an application and check the box "stay open after run handler". If you then double-click the saved application, when it runs it will show up in the OSX Dock like other running applications and it will stay open until you quit it. Try that.

Comment: thanks.  that worked.  I will try to do this with my script and see if it works.

Comment: I tried this with my script and it will scroll - which is great - but when I click the app icon in the dock bar it does not stop.  what part of your script above tells the scrolling to pause?

Comment: The flow is at first launch the "on run" handler first then "on idle" loops. The line "return 0.1" means the "idle handler runs every 0.1 seconds. When you click the dock icon the flow becomes "on reopen" and then "on idle". So you can see in the reopen handler that shouldScroll is toggled between true and false. Looking in the idle handler you can see the effect of that.

Comment: Thanks!  I got this to work.  What is interesting is your use of On Idle - which I haven't used before.  I don't know how frequently this gets called.  But in my old script, I used a Repeat option to scroll the page and had a small delay.

Comment: Using the Repeat option, the page scrolled smoothly.  Using the On Idle, it does not seem to get called frequently enough so the page scrolls very slowly.  I don't want to use large jumps in the scrolling.  Any ideas what I might try?

Comment: Never mind.  I figured out how to make On Idle get called more frequently using the Return value.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to see you worked through your problems. If you are satisfied with my answer please check it as answered. This way I get credit and everyone knows you have an answer. Good luck.

Comment: I will do that.  Another problem you solved for me was how to get a script to run each time a new page is loaded.  I did not think this could be done - but using the "application" "stay open" approach makes the script run again each time a new page is opened (well, i guess it's just the On Idle that is continuing to run).  Any way your solution was great.

Answer (score 0):

You might exit the script when the focused window becomes a normal browser window, by for example testing if the frontmost window has a full screen button:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    repeat until exists value of attribute "AXFullScreenButton" of window 1
        --do something
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

Or if the script is supposed to stop when Safari becomes the frontmost application:

```
repeat until frontmost of application "Safari"
    --do something
    delay 1
end repeat
```

Comment: The Safari window will always be frontmost.  I have an Applescript that slowly scrolls the Safari window.  I want to pause the scrolling when I click in the window.  But I can't figure out how to trap for a click event.